# Apache/Rails/Passenger directory URLs that don't end in '/' fail to 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, apache, passenger

I'm using Apache with passenger to run a rails app.  In my rails app, I have some static content in subdirectories of the public directory.  Each subdirectory has an index.html in it.

So, inside the public directory, I have a subdir called 'b' and inside it, is an index.html.  So it's like this:

/public/b/index.html

I have links to these pages, of the form:

http://a.com/b

If I do this in my regular non-rails web directory, Apache correctly rewrites this URL to be http://a.com/b/ which then, subsequently shows the index.html.  It's only when accessing my rails app that it doesn't work.  In fact, if I turn off passenger mod... so it just accesses my rails app like a regular document root, it works correctly also.

What the heck do I need to do to get this to work properly with passenger?  Again, it works fine in apache itself when passenger is not involved.

I am running passenger 2.1.3.  I have another server running passenger 2.0 that doesn't seem to have this problem, but I don't see anything different in the config other than the different versions of passenger itself.

HELP! Been working on this for two days solid with no improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [`PassengerHighPerformance`](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#PassengerHighPerformance) on?  That can interfere with index pages.

Comment: No I don't.  I reverted my passenger from 2.1.3 to 2.0.6 and the problem went away.  I think it's something broken in 2.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rewrite rule to your apache config:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
# For a given url foo, check if foo/index.html exists as a static file
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1/index.html [QSA]
```